# Simple mod_rewrite problem

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am new to using mod_rewrite and am trying to rewrite pages at the base level of my site:

www.site.com

I want to rewrite any of the following URLs www.site.com/main www.site.com/settings www.site.com/username

To: www.site.com/index.php?v=main www.site.com/index.php?v=settings www.site.com/index.php?v=username

I had this working when I had mod_rewrite set up under www.site.com/directory/ but can't figure out how to make it work with www.site.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra "/" there. That should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You don’t have to escape the dot inside a character class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The correct rule would be...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But you might hit some problems - for example if you have REAL directories - this will rewrite them too and prevent you from using them. You have two options to avoid the problem, you can write many rules, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^Directory/?$ index.php?v=directory [L,NC,QSA]
```

Or you can use a "pretend directory" like this...

```
RewriteRule ^Content/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

In the second example, your URL would be www.site.com/Content/Directory/

I've put NC and QSA on my attributes - No Case and Query String Append. You should definitely use NC, and QSA is useful in some implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I would settle on whether the path should be `/settings` or `/settings/` (you currently match both) and so on (personally, I prefer `/settings`.) I believe that it's a good idea to make paths as non-ambigous as possible. If you were to match paths like `/settings`, you would do like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Also have a look at the `QSA` flag if you want to support additional query parameters (for example: `/settings?tab=password` to `index.php?v=settings&tab=password`.) I'm mentioning it because that's something that bothered me in the beginning.